# Goto line by number in folded org buffer

Tags: org-mode

I looking for a way to go to the specific line by number in an org file, when the structure is folded. An ideal solution would be to unfold only necessary headings to put the cursor in the line. I was looking for a while for some solution for this, but I didn't find any silver bullet so far.

Comment: How about just stringing two functions together, such as `goto-line` and `org-show-entry`?  Like this:  `(defun goto-line-unfold-subtree () "Doc-string" (interactive) (call-interactively 'goto-line) (org-show-entry))`

Comment: @lawlist thanks, I tried this, it position cursor in correct line but only current heading is shown, all intermediate headings are kind of narrowed. Maybe the solution would be to infold entire tree, position the cursor and hide all not related branches.

Comment: How about `org-show-subtree` instead of `org-show-entry`?

Comment: Or, how about adding a third function in series?  E.g., `(defun goto-line-unfold-subtree () "Doc-string" (interactive) (call-interactively 'goto-line) (org-show-entry) (org-show-subtree))`

Comment: @lawlist it kind of works, but the result is messy. I get only 3 lines snippet on cursor new position, rest of the heading content is hidden behind "..." and can't be reveled without unfolding entire tree. I think unfolding entire tree and jumping to the location would be perfect, hidding other subtrees is optional.

Comment: The function `org-show-entry` contains a doc-string stating:  "*Show the body directly following this heading.  Show the heading too, if it is currently invisible.*"  Without an example set forth in the question with sample text we can all block and copy into a blank `org-mode` buffer to try this out, it is difficult for forum participants (at least it is for me) to envision what "only 3 lines snippet" looks like in the context of the subtrees and buffer.  Perhaps you can give us a sample of what this looks like BEFORE and a sample of what it should look like AFTER the custom function is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to try `M-x reveal-mode` which will automatically un-hide things so as to make the text around cursor visible.

Comment: I'm using org 9.6 and that just doesn't work. I have `reveal-mode` enabled, but after `M-g g`, it doesn't....well, reveal the surrounding context. I don't see any unfolding, just a jump to the visible headline that happens to contain that line. If I manually open that entry, and then do the same thing again, I can iteratively drill down, but that's not what I was expecting.

Comment: @DanDrake: You might like to `(setq org-fold-core-style 'overlays)` :-)

Comment: That works with goto-line, but seems to make other folding things work very strangely for me...

Comment: @DanDrake: I suggest you report it as a bug in Org or Emacs

Answer (score 1):

Here the function I use

```
(defadvice goto-line (after unfold-tree activate)
    (when (outline-invisible-p)
      (save-excursion
        (outline-previous-visible-heading 1)
        (org-show-subtree))))
```